# How can i customize the dropdown menu of bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css

I have problem customizing the dropdown menu of bootstrap, is there way to achieve when i hover the nav-item the nav item will automatically set a background color of white. to give more details I want to achieve this dropdown concept.

This is the sample image that I want to achieve on my dropdown.

[image: Achieve]

So currently I already create a navbar but I don't know how can i achieve that setting background-color to the navlink of bootstrap 4.

[image: My work]

I will share to you guys my sample code that I made.

```css
        .nav-item.dropdown:hover {
        background-color: #FFF;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-dark" style="min-height: 56px; background-color:#575A5D !important; border-color:#575A5D !important; position:fixed; width: 100%; z-index:3;">
 <button class="custom-toggler navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"  style="color:white !important;" data-target=".navbar1and2" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" style="color:white !important;"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar1and2" id="navbarSupportedContent2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" >
     <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           MEMBERSHIP
         </a>   
      <div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">Benefits For</p>
                 <div style="border-right-style: dotted;  height:auto; "></div>
                  <a href="./physician_membership.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; border-color:#00A0DF; background-color:#00A0DF; font-size:16.5px !important; "><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Physician</a>
                 <br><br>
                 <a href="./residents.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; border-color:#00A0DF; background-color:#00A0DF; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Residents & Fellows-in-Training</a>
                 <br><br>
                 <a href="./medical_students.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-radius: 50px; text-align: left;border-radius:  border-color:#00A0DF; background-color:#00A0DF; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medical Students</a>
                 <br><br>
                 <a href="./international_membership.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C; border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> International</a>
                 <br><br>
                 <a href="./affiliate_membership.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Affiliate</a>

               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">Become a Fellow</p>
                <ul style="list-style-type: circle; ">
                 <li><a href=""  style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Interested in becoming fellow?</a></li><br>
                 <li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Nominate a fellow <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:10px;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">For Members</p>
                <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                 <li><a href=""  style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="far fa-gem"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Pay Dues <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></a></li>
                 <br>
                 <li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-th-list"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Update Account <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></a></li>
                 <br>
                 <li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-money-check"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp; Check Orders <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           CME & MOC
         </a>
        
      <div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">

                <p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">UNDERSTANDING MOC</p>
                <p>PSMID offers a number of resources to help members make sense of the MOC requirements and earn points.</p>
                 
                
                <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-color:#007BFF; background-color:#007BFF; border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Understand MOC Requirements</a>
                <br><br>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#007BFF; background-color:#007BFF;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Earn MOC Points</a>

               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
                <p style="font-size:30px; color:#000">Industry Leading Tools & Resources</p>
                <ul style="list-style-type: none; ">
                 <li><a href=""  style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"> MKSAP 18</a></li><br>
                 <li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><img src="./Assets/annals_icon.png" class="img-fluid"> &nbsp;&nbsp;  Annals of IM </a></li>
                 <br>
                 <li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><img src="./Assets/im2020-57x57.png" class="img-fluid"> &nbsp;&nbsp;  Internal Medicine Meeting </a></li>
                </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:0px;">
                
                <div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                 <p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">CME</a> <br><br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">MOC</a> <br><br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Certification Preperation</a> <br> <br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Online Learning Center</a>
                </div>
                
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           MEETING & COURCES
         </a>
        
      <div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">

                <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><img src="./Assets/im2020-logo-350x115.png" class="img-fluid">
                <br><br>  
                <p style="font-size:18px; color:#8e908f;">The most comprehensive meeting in Internal Medicine.</p>
                <hr>
                
                <p style="font-size:27px; color:#8e908f;">Los Angeles,CA April 23-25, 2020</p>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:15px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> INTERNAL MEDICINE MEETING 2020</a>

               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
                <p style="font-size:30px; color:#000">Upcoming Internal Medicine Board Review Courses</p>
                <p style="font-size:20px; color:#8e908f">Prepare for the Certification and Maintenance of Certification (MOC) Exam with an PSMID review course.</p>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:15px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> BOARD CERTIFICATION REVIEW COURCES</a>
                <br><br>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:15px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> MOC EXAM PREP COURCES</a>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:0px;">
                
                <div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                 <p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Internal Medicine Meeting</a> <br><br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">US Chapter Meetings</a> <br><br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">International Chapter Meetings</a> <br> <br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Courses & Recordings</a>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Focused Topics</a>
                </div>
                
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         
       </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           CLINICAL INFORMATION
         </a>
        
      <div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-8" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">

                <center>
                 <br>
                 <div style="line-height: 5px;">

                  <p style="font-size:30px;">PSMID Clinical Search</p>
                  <h5 style="font-size:20px;">Treating a patient? Researching a topic? Get answers now.</h5>
                   
             
           
            <div class="input-group  col-md-7">
          
           <input type="text" class="form-control" style="position: relative; top:7px; font-size: 15px; "  placeholder="Search Clinical Information" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
           <div class="input-group-prepend" style="position: relative; top:7px;  ">
             <span class="input-group-text"  id="basic-addon1" style="background-color: #00A0DF !important; border-color:#00A0DF; color:white; "><i class="fas fa-search" style="font-size:15px;"></i></span>
           </div>

         </div>
         <br><br>
            <hr>

            <div class="container-fluid">
             <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
               <img src="./Assets/logo-annals3.png" class="img-fluid">
               <br><br><br><br><br>
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> VISIT ANNALS</a>
               <br><br><br><br>
               <a href="" style="font-size:15px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">LEARN MORE</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
               <img src="./Assets/logo-annals3.png" class="img-fluid">
               <br><br><br><br><br>
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> VISIT MKSAP 18</a>
               <br><br><br><br>
               <a href="" style="font-size:15px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">LEARN MORE</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
               <img src="./Assets/dmp_logo_v3.png" class="img-fluid">
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> VISIT DYNAMED PLUS</a>
               
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
       
            
                 </div>
                </center>
                

               </div>
               
               <div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:0px;">
                
                <div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                 <p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Clinical Guidelines & Recommendations</a> <br><br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Performance Measures</a> <br><br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Journals & Publications</a> <br> <br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Clinical Resources & Products</a>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">High Value Care</a> <br> <br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Ethics & Professionalism</a>
                </div>
                
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         
       </li>
       
 <!--       <li class="nav-item " style="padding-right:60px; color:white;">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#" >CLINICAL INFORMATION</a>
       </li> -->

         <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           PRACTICE RESOURCES
         </a>
        
      <div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-3" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">

                <p style="font-size:25px; color:#8e908f">Medicare</p>
                <p style="font-size:18px;">Ensure payment and avoid policy violations. Plus, new resources to help you navigate the Medicare Access and CHIP Reauthorization Act of 2015 (MACRA).</p>
                 
                <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medicare Resources</a>

               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
                <p style="font-size:25px; color:#8e908f">Office Forms</p>
                <p style="font-size:18px;">Access helpful forms developed by a variety of sources for patient charts, logs, information sheets, office signs, and use by practice administration.</p>
                 
                <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Office Forms</a>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6" style=" position: relative; top:10px;">
                <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                  <p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">QUICK LINKS</p>
                  <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                   <li><a href=""  style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> QPP/MACRA </a></li>
                   <br>
                   <li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i>Physician & Practice Timeline </a></li>
                   <br>
                   <li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Coding</a></li>
                   <br>
                   <li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medical Educator Resources</a></li>

                  </ul>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                   <p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
                   <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">CME</a> <br><br>
                   <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">MOC</a> <br><br>
                   <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Certification Preperation</a> <br> <br>
                   <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Online Learning Center</a>
                  </div>
                 </div>
                </div>
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         
       </li>

       <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           ADVOCACY
         </a>
        
      <div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:auto; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-8" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
                
             <br>
             <div style="line-height: 5px;">

              <p style="font-size:30px;">Where We Stand</p>
              <h5 style="font-size:20px;">PSMID advocates on behalf on internists and their patients on a number of timely issues. Learn about where PSMID stands on the following areas:</h5>
              
           
             </div>
             <br>
             <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Access to Care</a>
               <br><br>
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Patients Before Paperwork</a>
               <br><br>
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medicare and the Quality Payment Program</a>
               <br><br>
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medicaid Reform</a>
               <br><br>
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Public Health</a>
               
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Physician Workforce and Team Based Care</a>
               <br><br>
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Women in Medicine</a>
               <br><br>
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Health Information Technology</a>
               <br><br>
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medical Liability Reform</a>
              </div>
             </div>
             <br>
               </div>
               
               <div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:0px;">
                
                <div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                 <p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Where We Stand</a> <br><br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">PSMID Advocate Newsletter</a> <br><br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">State Health Policy</a> <br> <br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Advocacy in Action</a>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Current Public Policy Papers</a> <br> <br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">PSMID Policies & Recommendations</a>
                </div>
                
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item " style="color:white !important;">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#" style=""><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> STORE</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[image: wrong output]

Comment: create a fiddle and upload u r code with css.

Comment: noted for this amaresh

Comment: Can you try to put code in Fiddle ? Plus, please try not to hardcode style in HTML code when you can. Use a separate CSS sheet, that will make your code more readable ;)

Comment: hi guys, i already add my fiddle thank you...

Comment: @AmareshSM yah your right. but the background color not in center.. can you adjust it on center..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `:hover` selector to the item you want with a `background-color` attribute. You also need to move around some of the `padding-right:50px` from the `<a>` tags and change them to `margin-right:50px` on the parent element. You can remove the `min-height:56px` from the `.navbar` element since the `.nav-items are centered vertically otherwise there will be a gap.

```
.navbar {
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
}
.nav-item {
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    margin-right:50px;
}
.nav-item:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
.nav-item:hover a {
    color:gray !important;
}
```

[Full Example Here](https://codepen.io/npfries/pen/QeOezZ)

Comment: not working sorry, i will show you the output if I add that code on my css

Comment: sorry same output nothing change

Comment: Edited for complete example

Comment: your on the correct path. but the background color not in the centered. the background color is moving on the right side.

Answer (score 1):

Are u expecting like this:

```css
.navbar{
padding:0px !important;
}

a#navbarDropdown:hover {
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: gray !important;
    height: 100%;
}
.nav-item{
  min-height:56px;
}
.nav-link{
  line-height:56px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-dark" style="height: 56px; background-color:#575A5D !important; border-color:#575A5D !important; position:fixed; width: 100%; z-index:3;">
<button class="custom-toggler navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"  style="color:white !important;" data-target=".navbar1and2" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon" style="color:white !important;"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar1and2" id="navbarSupportedContent2">
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" >
<li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
MEMBERSHIP
</a>   
<div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
<p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">Benefits For</p>
<div style="border-right-style: dotted;  height:auto; "></div>
<a href="./physician_membership.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; border-color:#00A0DF; background-color:#00A0DF; font-size:16.5px !important; "><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Physician</a>
<br><br>
<a href="./residents.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; border-color:#00A0DF; background-color:#00A0DF; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Residents & Fellows-in-Training</a>
<br><br>
<a href="./medical_students.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-radius: 50px; text-align: left;border-radius:  border-color:#00A0DF; background-color:#00A0DF; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medical Students</a>
<br><br>
<a href="./international_membership.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C; border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> International</a>
<br><br>
<a href="./affiliate_membership.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Affiliate</a>

</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
<p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">Become a Fellow</p>
<ul style="list-style-type: circle; ">
<li><a href=""  style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Interested in becoming fellow?</a></li><br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Nominate a fellow <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:10px;">
<p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">For Members</p>
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
<li><a href=""  style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="far fa-gem"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Pay Dues <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></a></li>
<br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-th-list"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Update Account <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></a></li>
<br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-money-check"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp; Check Orders <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
CME & MOC
</a>

<div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">

<p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">UNDERSTANDING MOC</p>
<p>PSMID offers a number of resources to help members make sense of the MOC requirements and earn points.</p>


<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-color:#007BFF; background-color:#007BFF; border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Understand MOC Requirements</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#007BFF; background-color:#007BFF;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Earn MOC Points</a>

</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
<p style="font-size:30px; color:#000">Industry Leading Tools & Resources</p>
<ul style="list-style-type: none; ">
<li><a href=""  style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"> MKSAP 18</a></li><br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><img src="./Assets/annals_icon.png" class="img-fluid"> &nbsp;&nbsp;  Annals of IM </a></li>
<br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><img src="./Assets/im2020-57x57.png" class="img-fluid"> &nbsp;&nbsp;  Internal Medicine Meeting </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:0px;">

<div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
<p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">CME</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">MOC</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Certification Preperation</a> <br> <br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Online Learning Center</a>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
MEETING & COURCES
</a>

<div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">

<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><img src="./Assets/im2020-logo-350x115.png" class="img-fluid">
<br><br>  
<p style="font-size:18px; color:#8e908f;">The most comprehensive meeting in Internal Medicine.</p>
<hr>

<p style="font-size:27px; color:#8e908f;">Los Angeles,CA April 23-25, 2020</p>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:15px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> INTERNAL MEDICINE MEETING 2020</a>

</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
<p style="font-size:30px; color:#000">Upcoming Internal Medicine Board Review Courses</p>
<p style="font-size:20px; color:#8e908f">Prepare for the Certification and Maintenance of Certification (MOC) Exam with an PSMID review course.</p>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:15px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> BOARD CERTIFICATION REVIEW COURCES</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:15px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> MOC EXAM PREP COURCES</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:0px;">

<div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
<p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Internal Medicine Meeting</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">US Chapter Meetings</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">International Chapter Meetings</a> <br> <br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Courses & Recordings</a>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Focused Topics</a>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</li>

<li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
CLINICAL INFORMATION
</a>

<div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-8" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">

<center>
<br>
<div style="line-height: 5px;">

<p style="font-size:30px;">PSMID Clinical Search</p>
<h5 style="font-size:20px;">Treating a patient? Researching a topic? Get answers now.</h5>



<div class="input-group  col-md-7">

<input type="text" class="form-control" style="position: relative; top:7px; font-size: 15px; "  placeholder="Search Clinical Information" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
<div class="input-group-prepend" style="position: relative; top:7px;  ">
<span class="input-group-text"  id="basic-addon1" style="background-color: #00A0DF !important; border-color:#00A0DF; color:white; "><i class="fas fa-search" style="font-size:15px;"></i></span>
</div>

</div>
<br><br>
<hr>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="./Assets/logo-annals3.png" class="img-fluid">
<br><br><br><br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> VISIT ANNALS</a>
<br><br><br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:15px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">LEARN MORE</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="./Assets/logo-annals3.png" class="img-fluid">
<br><br><br><br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> VISIT MKSAP 18</a>
<br><br><br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:15px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">LEARN MORE</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="./Assets/dmp_logo_v3.png" class="img-fluid">
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> VISIT DYNAMED PLUS</a>

</div>
</div>
</div>


</div>
</center>


</div>

<div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:0px;">

<div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
<p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Clinical Guidelines & Recommendations</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Performance Measures</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Journals & Publications</a> <br> <br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Clinical Resources & Products</a>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">High Value Care</a> <br> <br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Ethics & Professionalism</a>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</li>

<!--       <li class="nav-item " style="padding-right:60px; color:white;">
<a class="nav-link" href="#" >CLINICAL INFORMATION</a>
</li> -->

<li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
PRACTICE RESOURCES
</a>

<div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-3" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">

<p style="font-size:25px; color:#8e908f">Medicare</p>
<p style="font-size:18px;">Ensure payment and avoid policy violations. Plus, new resources to help you navigate the Medicare Access and CHIP Reauthorization Act of 2015 (MACRA).</p>

<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medicare Resources</a>

</div>
<div class="col-md-3" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
<p style="font-size:25px; color:#8e908f">Office Forms</p>
<p style="font-size:18px;">Access helpful forms developed by a variety of sources for patient charts, logs, information sheets, office signs, and use by practice administration.</p>

<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Office Forms</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" style=" position: relative; top:10px;">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">QUICK LINKS</p>
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
<li><a href=""  style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> QPP/MACRA </a></li>
<br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i>Physician & Practice Timeline </a></li>
<br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Coding</a></li>
<br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medical Educator Resources</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
<p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">CME</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">MOC</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Certification Preperation</a> <br> <br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Online Learning Center</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</li>

<li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
ADVOCACY
</a>

<div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:auto; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-8" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">

<br>
<div style="line-height: 5px;">

<p style="font-size:30px;">Where We Stand</p>
<h5 style="font-size:20px;">PSMID advocates on behalf on internists and their patients on a number of timely issues. Learn about where PSMID stands on the following areas:</h5>


</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Access to Care</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Patients Before Paperwork</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medicare and the Quality Payment Program</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medicaid Reform</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Public Health</a>

</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Physician Workforce and Team Based Care</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Women in Medicine</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Health Information Technology</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medical Liability Reform</a>
</div>
</div>
<br>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:0px;">

<div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
<p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Where We Stand</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">PSMID Advocate Newsletter</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">State Health Policy</a> <br> <br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Advocacy in Action</a>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Current Public Policy Papers</a> <br> <br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">PSMID Policies & Recommendations</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="nav-item " style="color:white !important;">
<a class="nav-link" href="#" style=""><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> STORE</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: your on the correct path. but the background color not in the centered. the background color is moving on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove all of the inline styles as there are overriding the stylesheets

```
.navbar.navbar-light.bg-dark li a.nav-link{
     color:white;
}

.navbar.navbar-light.bg-dark li:hover a.nav-link{
     color:#00A0DF;!important
}
```

so instead of having

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              MEMBERSHIP
            </a>
```

use

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  role="button" data- 
toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">MEMBERSHIP</a>
```